# Angular & NativeScript - Auto generated works, what now?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have been using Angular now for 18 months and decided to try the water and convert web app to mobile app using Native Script. After a few days of giving small turtle steps I am now in a position where I have an Android emulator installed and working and using Visual Studio Code I can still 'Serve' and 'Build' my web app and running 'tns run android --bundle' based on https://blog.angular.io/apps-that-work-natively-on-the-web-and-mobile-9b26852495e7 Too make long story short the icon for the app is now generated in the simulator so 'Yeah' If I click on the app it opens with 'NativeScript' splash screen (which I am sure I will be able to tackle) BUT the landing page is then simply 'auto-generated works' So my question is, does anyone know what next?? Of course I would like the 'index.html' screen from the web app to appear as landing page for mobile app so I can see code in action but struggling to figure out next step.

Comment: seems that doesn't run on emulators https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-preview/

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript is not Hybrid platform like Cordova / PhoneGap, hence you can not reuse your web app completely. It uses native components, comes with a set of UI controls you could use to build the app / screens (while you can extend and use any third party controls too).

The JavaScript runtime helps you to reuse your web skills such as HTML (more of XML), JS / TS, CSS / SCSS, Angular / React / Vue etc., You will have to rebuild your entire UI but you could still reuse your business logic, controllers etc., Basically anything that involves DOM Elements or Browser features should be rewritten.

You must go through the getting [started guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/technical-overview), get familiar with layouts and UI controls to build your screen. NativeScript uses [page-router-outlet](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation) instead of router-outlet, which is nothing but an extended version to meet specific requirements of iOS / Android navigation. Eventually you may need [plugins](https://market.nativescript.org/) to build any advanced controls / features.

Comment: Thanks Manoj. Appreciate feedback. I understand what you saying but not sure about "You will have to rebuild your entire UI" I sort of was hoping that if there is no tns file for a component that the mobile app will revert to the decorator "name.component.tns.html" in the shared "name.component.tns" file. I can't find any proof of this so just asking.  Perhaps I need to explain my goal. I have developed a few web apps over the past year with Angular and have been asked by the clients what would be involved to 'convert' the web apps to mobile apps. I understand NativeScript not Hybrid platform.

Comment: I think it would revert to web if no `*.tns.*` extension is found, you would have probably created TNS specific app module & main files which will not load any existing components by default.